# How to use variable in xsl inside select, where variable is reference to another xml file

Tags: xml, xslt

I have two xml files. I have variable in xsl file which is referenced to another file as you see below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings" extension-element-prefixes="str">
   <xsl:variable name="testing" select="document('test2.xml')//methods"/>
   .....
   .....
   <xsl:variable name="className" select="@Class" />
   <xsl:value-of select="$testing/myClass/@domainName" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This works if I don't use variable and use direct text, which is here myClass but if I use variable then its not working.

e.g
 `<xsl:value-of select="$testing/$className/@domainName" />` --> don't work

or
`<xsl:value-of select="$testing/${className}/@domainName" />` --> don't work

or
`<xsl:value-of select="concat($testing,'/',$className,'/',@domainName" />` --> don't work

Please help me here, how can I use normal variable with referenced variable?Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `$testing/*[local-name() = $className]/@domainName`.